# How to enable all plugins

Tags: ckeditor

Having downloaded the ckeditor 'Full Package' there are 61 plugins in the /plugin directory but none seem to be enabled.  How do I enable all plugins which ship with the 'Full Package'?

Comment: What does it mean that the plugins are not enabled? If you download any of the pre-defined presets (Basic, Standard, Full), check the sample from the `samples/index.html` file - everything should work.

Comment: I think I assumed too much of CKEditor - Things like 'Save' don't actually work and I believed that was because the plugin wasn't enabled.  The answer is that much funcionallty of CKEdit doesn't actually work straight out of the box.

Comment: Some features require some setup/configuration on your part to work, to integrate them with some parts of your server side, application, file manager etc.